# How do I determine maximum/minimum of this multivariable function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Determine maximum and minimum of function
$f\left(x,y\right)=x^{3}+y^{3}$
on range $B=\left\{ \left(x,y\right): x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1  \right\}  $ Show that maximum and minimum can only be on this range and determine behaviour of this function.

I am really confused in this example because of B that is given.

I found first and second partial derivatives and got that maximum/minimum is in 0,0 which cant be  here. Can someone help me with this? What should I do?

Comment: Hint: You found the minimum in $B$, to find the max, since there were no other critical points, the max(es) must be on the boundary of $B$.

Comment: You computed the 2nd partial derivatives and can't tell whether a minimum or maximum is attained at the origin?

Comment: @JustinBenfield So minimum is 0,0? But can I find/show that boundary of B?

Comment: It's not actually the minimum (why?). Can you picture what this surface looks like? (Hint: Think about $x,z$-plane and $y,z$-plane first, what does curve in those planes look like, now what the rest of the surface?)

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:**

The extrema are either inside the interior of $B$ or on the boundary. Split up the problem and find first the local extrema in the interior, then on the boundary.

Local extrema in the interior can simply be found by solving the gradient equal to zero, and then checking if the points are inside $B$.

For finding local extrema on the boundary, parametrize it by setting $(x,y) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ for $t\in [-\pi, \pi).$ This will reduce your problem to one dimension since $f(\cos t, \sin t) = \cos(t)^3+\sin(t)^3$ depends only on $t$. Now find the extrema of this function in the usual way (calculating the derivative with respect to $t$ and solving it for zero).

Comment: I got pi/4. And what now with that?

Answer (score 0):

A more detailed solution building off of Eff's hint:

The maxima/minima either occur in the interior of the boundary or on the edge of $B$.

Interior:

We can use the gradient of the function and set it to zero in order to find extrema.

$$\nabla f(x,y)=\langle3x^2,3y^2\rangle=\langle0,0\rangle$$

So, the only extremum in the interior of the $B$ is $(0,0)$ as you pointed out. Note that $f(0,0)=0$

Edge:

Let's substitute $x$ with $\cos t$ and $y$ with $\sin t$. 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\sin^3 t+\cos^3 t\right)=0$$ 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\sin^3 t+\frac{d}{dt}\cos^3 t=0$$
$$3\sin^2t\cdot\cos t-3\cos^2t\cdot\sin t = 0$$
The possible values of $t$ in the range $[0,2\pi)$ are $0$, $\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$, $\frac{5\pi}{4}$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Plugging these values back into the original expression, we find that the maxima occur at $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$, while the minima occur at $\pi$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Now, $0$ corresponds to $(1,0)$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$ corresponds to $(0,1)$, $\pi$ corresponds to $(-1,0)$, and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ corresponds to $(0,-1)$.

Note that $f(1,0)=f(0,1)=1$ and $f(-1,0)=f(0,-1)=-1$. We can now see that the interior point $(0,0)$ is just an extremum, not a maximum or minimum.

Comment: Ok I think I understand mostly, but what is at the end maximum and minimum? 1 and -1?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic Yep, that is correct.